# Scala syntax problem

Tags: scala

The following code can be compiled

```
  def isEven(a:Int)=
    if (a%2==0) true else false

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
        List(1, 10) filter isEven foreach println
```

but if I change to following ( List(1,10) --> List(1 to 10))

```
def isEven(a:Int)=
    if (a%2==0) true else false

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
        List(1 to 10) filter isEven foreach println
   }
```

What's difference between List(1,10) and List(1 to 10) ?

Comment: Minor note: isEven (a) returns true, if (a%2==0) is true, and false, if it is false, so it returns effectively (a % 2 == 0) - nothing more. And what about `println ((1 to 10) filter isEven)`?

Comment: @user I'm half of a mind of down-voting this question on that line of code alone. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List(1, 2)` is simply a list with two `Int` elements: 1 and 2. The expression `1 to 10` creates a `Range` instance, so `List(1 to 10)` is a list with one element: a `Range`.

Answer (score 3):

`List(1, 10)` is a `List[Int]` whereas `List(1 to 10)` is a `List[Range]`. Observe the types in the following REPL session:

```
scala> 1 to 10
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive with scala.collection.immutable.Range.ByOne = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
, 8, 9, 10)

scala> List(1 to 10)
res4: List[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive with scala.collection.immutable.Range.ByOne] = List(Range(1, 2, 3,
 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

scala> List(1, 10)
res5: List[Int] = List(1, 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

missingfaktor is right, so this is just an addition.

If you want a `List[Int]` with numbers from 1 to 10, you can write

```
List(1 to 10:_*)
```

or

```
1 to 10 toList
```